# Set CSS 'top' property using Javascript depending on mouse position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to set the `top` CSS property through JavaScript.

If I use an absolute value like 100px it works just fine, but if I try to get the mouse position using `event.clientX`, it does not work.

Please note that I do not want to use jQuery or other libraries.

Code so far:

```
var el = document.getElementById('hide');

document.getElementById("foo").onmouseover = function() {
  el.style.border = "5px solid red";
  el.style.display = "block";
  el.style.top = '100px'; // This works
  el.style.top = event.clientX; // However this does not work
};
```

HTML:

```
<div id="foo">
  <p>
  Hover me
  </p>
</div>

#hide {
  display:none;
}
```

See also [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ef6dh3tn/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to add units to size declarations. Also, not sure if you intentionally used clientX and top, as the x-axis goes left-right and top property sets the up-down distance. The result (using top and clientX as you do) could look like this:

```
var el = document.getElementById('hide');

document.getElementById("foo").onmouseover = function() {
  el.style.border = "5px solid red";
  el.style.display = "block";
  var position = event.clientX + 'px';
  el.style.top = position;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked and yes the clientX, rather than Y, was intentional!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't passed the event to your function. Also, you're missing 'px'. Try this:

```
var el = document.getElementById('hide');

document.getElementById("foo").onmouseover = function(event) {
  el.style.border = "5px solid red";
  el.style.display = "block";
  el.style.top = event.clientX + 'px';
};
```

Comment: I really wonder how exactly the accepted answer worked, since it doesn't contain the event assignment to the function :)